how to create GLSurfaceView with a custom EGLSurface
creating a GLSurfaceView and setting setEGLWindowSurfaceFactory() to override createWindowSurface()
createWindowSurface() must return javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLSurface
my surface is created using EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface() which returns android.opengl.EGLSurface not javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLSurface
how can i return android.opengl.EGLSurface?

GLSurfaceView is an old class that hasn't been updated for a long time.
Looks like the only way to implement a custom EGLWindowSurfaceFactory is to create an javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLSurface
by calling EGL10.eglCreateWindowSurface() instead of EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface() which returns a android.opengl.EGLSurface.
Both types of EGLSurface are wrapper classes for the native EGLSurface object.
